# Basic forEach not working with Angular/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to rewrite my mobile apps using the latest Angular 6/Ionic 4. I just can't seem to get a basic `forEach` working. I'm trying all types of ways, but Sublime Text & Angular CLI throws errors. Please see the screenshot below. You can see the red squiggly lines in the Sublime Text Editor. The error is commented above each code block. Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong?

[image: Screenshot of forEach Errors]

Thanks for your time - please don't hesitate to let me know if you need additional info.

```
array = [1, 2, 3];

  // Duplicate identifier 'array'. -- Parameter declaration expected.
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
  })

  // Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
  this.array.forEach((key : any, val: any) => {
    console.log(val);
  })

  // Cannot find name 'array'. Did you mean 'Array'?
  array.forEach((key : any, val: any) => {
    console.log(val);
  })

  // Cannot find name 'array'. Did you mean 'Array'?
  for (let number of array) {
   console.log(number);
  }
```

Comment: What if you do `let array = [...]`?

Comment: please add whole file, it seems it's not forEach problem

Comment: I'd look at some of the syntax here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html number may be reserved? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2536

Comment: Post your code **as text**. We can't copy and paste code from an image. Blind people can't read code in an image.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry - just wanted you to see the squigglys in the editor. Will post code next time.

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=array%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%0D%0Afor%20(let%20e%20of%20array)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(e)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A

Comment: @NickyTheWrench If you want to *also* add an image for additional context, that's fine too.  But the actual text needs to be there for a number of reasons.  It makes it more accessible to people with vision problems, it allows search engines to see it (so other people with the same problem can find it more easily), and it allows people who want to test your problem to copy/paste the code.

Comment: Or: `array = [1,2,3]
array.forEach((e) => alert(e))`

Comment: Added code to the question for future readers - thanks again everyone for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be inside methods to access component variables. Try your code in some methods or in constructor.
Something like:
constructor() {
 Your code
}

Its not required that you should call it in constructor only, you can call the component variables through any methods by using this.componentVaribale inside a method. Obviously you can create local variables in methods using 'let' keyword!

Comment: Yup - needed to put it in the constructor, thanks so much. Will accept answer soon.

Comment: just to clarify, its not required that you should call it in constructor only, you can call the component variables through any methods by using this.componentVaribale inside a method. Obviously you can create local variables in methods using 'let' keyword!

Comment: @alokstar, you might want to add that to the answer.

Comment: @alokstar thanks for the clarification and your time.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Issue

You have issue with variable declaration scoping.

> ### Fix

#### Change 1 : Local variable

let array = [1,2,3]

#### Change 2 : Accessing instance variable by `this`.

If you want to access `this` you must use inside the function.

```
function test(){
   this.array.forEach(function(){});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time!